# Represent negative timedelta in most basic form

Tags: pandas, timedelta, python-datetime

If I create a negative `Timedelta` for e.g. 0.5 hours, the internal representation looks as follow:

```
In [2]: pd.Timedelta('-0.5h')
Out[2]: Timedelta('-1 days +23:30:00')
```

How can I get back a (`str`) representation of this `Timedelta` in the form `-00:30`?

I want to display these deltas and requiring the user to calculate the expression -1 day + something is a bit award.

Comment: Is possible use `print (pd.Timedelta('-0.5h').total_seconds() / 60)` ?

Comment: Something that better handles different time ranges would be nicer

Comment: maybe it is more python question as pandas, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8408397/2901002)

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comment to you so adding it here. Don't know if this helps but I think you can use python humanize.

```
import humanize as hm
hm.naturaltime((pd.Timedelta('-0.5h')))
```

Out:

```
'30 minutes from now'
```

Comment: That would be an interesting thing, however, the "some time ago" metaphor doesn't work in this case as it is just an offset that I am representing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will live with a hack going trough a date:

```
sign = ''
date = pd.to_datetime('today')
if delta.total_seconds() < 0:
    sign = '-'
    date = date - delta
else:
    date = date + delta

print '{}{:%H:%M}'.format(sign, date.to_pydatetime())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `components` of a Pandas timedelta

```
import pandas as pd
t = pd.Timedelta('-0.5h')
print t.components

>> Components(days=-1L, hours=23L, minutes=30L, seconds=0L, milliseconds=0L, microseconds=0L, nanoseconds=0L)
```

You can access each component with

```
print t.components.days
>> -1
print t.components.hours
>> 23
print t.components.minutes
>> 30
```

The rest is then formatting.

*[source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html)*

---

This is a total hack that won't work for Series data, but....

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
t = pd.Timedelta('-0.5h').components
mins =  t.days*24*60 + t.hours*60 + t.minutes

print str(np.sign(mins))[0]+str(divmod(abs(mins), 60)[0]).zfill(2)+':'+str(divmod(abs(mins), 60)[1]).zfill(2)

>> -00:30
```

Comment: But "just the formatting" is quite some work in case there can be deltas of different time ranges.

Comment: This is programming. Getting a machine to "think" like a human is indeed "quite some work".

Comment: I was hoping for some automated way where someone has done the same thing before.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar (see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17232 )

I'm not sure if it will be implemented in Pandas, so here is a workaround

```
import pandas as pd


def timedelta2str(td, display_plus=False, format=None):
    """

    Parameters
    ----------
    format : None|all|even_day|sub_day|long
    Returns
    -------
    converted : string of a Timedelta

    >>> td = pd.Timedelta('00:00:00.000')
    >>> timedelta2str(td)
    '0 days'

    >>> td = pd.Timedelta('00:01:29.123')
    >>> timedelta2str(td, display_plus=True, format='sub_day')
    '+ 00:01:29.123000'

    >>> td = pd.Timedelta('-00:01:29.123')
    >>> timedelta2str(td, display_plus=True, format='sub_day')
    '- 00:01:29.123000'

    """
    td_zero = pd.Timedelta(0)
    sign_sep = ' '
    if td >= td_zero:
        s = td._repr_base(format=format)
        if display_plus:
            s = "+" + sign_sep + s
        return s
    else:
        s = timedelta2str(-td, display_plus=False, format=format)
        s = "-" + sign_sep + s
        return s


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```