# Python difference in datetime now against datetime now

Tags: python, datetime, diff

I have got into an issue or might quite possibly feature in turn! Not sure, wondering!! In python's datetime library, to get difference in time, as in below snippet.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.timedelta(-1, 86399, 999958)
>>> tnow = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> datetime.datetime.now() - tnow
datetime.timedelta(0, 4, 327859)
```

I would like to understand why `datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now()` is producing output as **-1 days, 86399 seconds** whereas assigning current time to some variable and computing difference gives desired output **0 days, 4 seconds**.

The results seems to be bit confusing, it would be helpful if someone could decode whats going behind

Note: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: the first statement gives datetime.now - datetime.now which is like 15:55 - 15:55. I don't know what it should return but it isn't what you want I assume. the second one records the time of when a variable is set then gets the time  now vs that time. not sure why it would return 4 seconds though... 4 seconds to go through datetime.now - tnow?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now()` returns `datetime.timedelta(0)`. I can think of an explanation... how slow is your machine? I'd bet you can't reproduce it every time you want.

Comment: Looks like it only happens in python 2. In python 3, I get `datetime.timedelta(0)`

Comment: problem solved: its the python versioning. python 2.x gives bad output for datetime.now - datetime.now but python 3.x is fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation for [`timedelta` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

> Note that normalization of negative values may be surprising at first.
> For example:
>
> ```
> >>> from datetime import timedelta
> >>> d = timedelta(microseconds=-1)
> >>> (d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)
> (-1, 86399, 999999)
> ```

This occurs in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.

The reason for the observed result is simple:

```
a , b = datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now()
# here datetime.now() in a will be <= b.
# That is because they will be executed separately at different CPU clock cycle.

a - b
# datetime.timedelta(-1, 86399, 999973)

b - a
# datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 27)
```

To get the proper time difference:

```
(tnow - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds()
# output: -1.751166
```

See also [Python timedelta issue with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408397).

Answer (score 2):

You are encountering a "corner case" situation.

- Every `datetime.datetime.now()` produces a `datetime.datetime` object ([[Python]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)), which is the current date & time **at the moment** the call was made
- You have 2 such calls (even if they are on the same line). Since the *CPU* speeds are very high nowadays, every such call takes a very small amount of time (much less than microseconds, I presume)
- But, when the 1<sup>st</sup> call is at the very end of a (microsecond?) period, and the 2<sup>nd</sup> one is at the beginning of the next one, you'd get this behavior:

> ```
> >>> import datetime
>
> >>> now0 = datetime.datetime.now()
> >>> now0
> datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 20, 12, 23, 23, 1000)
> >>> delta = datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1)
> >>> now1 = now0 + delta
> >>> now0 - now1
> datetime.timedelta(-1, 86399, 999999)
> ```

**Explanation**:

- Let `now0` to be the result of the 1<sup>st</sup> call made to `datetime.datetime.now()`
- Let's say that the 2<sup>nd</sup> `datetime.datetime.now()` call happens one microsecond later (I am reproducing the behavior using the `delta` object, as the times involved here are waaay too small for me to be able to to run the line at the **exact** time when this behavior is encountered). That is placed into `now1`
- When subtracting them you get the negative value (in my case is `-delta`), since `now0` happened earlier than `now1` (check [[Python]:  timedelta Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) for more details)