# Determine if x is positive for both floats and timedeltas

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, timedelta

I'm looking for a simple and neat way to check if a variable is positive where this can be either a float or a `numpy.timedelta64` or `datetime.timedelta`.

I obviously tried `x>0`, but this doesn't work for `timedelta`s (neither `numpy`'s or `datetime`'s)

The only solution i found is `x/abs(x) > 0` that I find somehow cumbersome. Not even `np.sign` returns an answer.

Is there a better way to check this?

EDIT:
Using `x.total_seconds()` returns an error whenever `x` is a float. Using `x > np.timedelta(0)` does not work for `datetime.timedelta`s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python timedelta issue with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408397/python-timedelta-issue-with-negative-values)

Comment: If i use `x.total_seconds()` I get an error whenever `x` is a `float`

Comment: if isinstance(x, timedelta):
    return x.total_seconds() > 0
else:
    return x > 0

Comment: Sure. But I would need to add one case for `np,timedelta64`, one for `datetime.timedelta` (as they are different classes) and one for floats. If this is the best, I think `x/abs(x)>0`is still a better solution.

Comment: x==abs(x) seems to work with both. You may need a check for zero though.

Answer (score 3):

You can compare against a "zero time-delta" object, then use `try` / `except` to cover numeric inputs:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

def pos_check(x, zero_value=timedelta()):
    try:
        return x > zero_value
    except TypeError:
        return x > 0

py_td = timedelta(days=1)      # 1-day, regular Python
np_td = np.timedelta64(py_td)  # 1-day, NumPy

assert pos_check(1.5)
assert pos_check(py_td)
assert pos_check(np_td)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use pandas, you can first cast all input types to a pandas Timedelta, and then check for positivity in a single line:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

def pos_check(x, zero_value=pd.Timedelta(0,'s')):
    return pd.Timedelta(x) > zero_value

py_td = timedelta(days=1)      # 1-day, regular Python
np_td = np.timedelta64(py_td)  # 1-day, NumPy
pd_td = pd.Timedelta(np_td)

assert pos_check(1.5)
assert pos_check(py_td)
assert pos_check(np_td)
assert pos_check(pd_td)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @NickChapman noted, using `isinstance` is probably easier (to read). Dont forget you can test the type of data against many classes at once:

```
def check_positive(x):
    if isinstance(x, (datetime.timedelta, np.timedelta64)):
        return x.total_seconds() > 0
    else:
        return x > 0
```