# why datetime.now() and constructed datetime using all fields(like year,month...) of now has big timedelta?

Tags: python, datetime

I have to add a line before the code or it won't display properly

```
now = datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day
hour = now.hour
minute = now.minute
second = now.second
testTime = datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)
print testTime - now
```

The code above give me result like this :-1 day, 23:59:59.106000,but it should be only microseconds,right?

The funny thing is if I add 1 to a field,say minute,it will give me the right answer.

Does anyone know what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: You have them backwards. `print now - testTime`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python timedelta issue with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408397/python-timedelta-issue-with-negative-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output is correct. It's telling you that, in order to make `testTime` equal to `now`, you'd need to subtract one day from `testTime` (that's the `-1 day`), then add back 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds, and 106000 microseconds. Effectively, that's saying "`testTime` is 894000 microseconds before `now`", which is correct; you truncated off the microseconds, making`testTime` ever-so-slightly earlier than `now`.

Are you sure you didn't flip your operands? `print(now - testTime)` would output `0:00:00.894000` which is probably the output you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks,you are totally right.And when I use print (testTime - now).total_seconds(),it give me something like -0.255.That's more readable.